# Pandas rearrenging columns with MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I need to perform rearrenging column operations that include:

find difference respect to a list 
create new columns sortes as list
Keep multiindex

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['c1','c2','c3','c4']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,2,2,3,3],[4,4,5,5,6,6],[7,7,8,8,9,9]],index=['r1','r2','r3'],columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('c2','mean'),('c2','max'),('c1','mean'),('c1','max'),('c3','mean'),('c3','max')]))

df
Out[52]: 
     c2       c1       c3    
   mean max mean max mean max
r1    1   1    2   2    3   3
r2    4   4    5   5    6   6
r3    7   7    8   8    9   9
```

so, the final result is:

```
df
Out[52]: 
     c1       c2       c3       c4    
   mean max mean max mean max mean max
r1    2   2    1   1    3   3  NaN NaN
r2    5   5    4   4    6   6  NaN NaN
r3    8   8    7   7    9   9  NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for change order and also add missing combinations to original data with new `MultiIndex`, e.g. created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['c1','c2','c3','c4'], ['mean','max']])
df = df.reindex(mux, axis=1)
print (df)
     c1       c2       c3       c4    
   mean max mean max mean max mean max
r1    2   2    1   1    3   3  NaN NaN
r2    5   5    4   4    6   6  NaN NaN
r3    8   8    7   7    9   9  NaN NaN
```